# For each "sub item" in json array, get name, then the value for a sub item

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I apologize for the poor title. I'll try to explain what I want to achieve as best as I can.

Here is my (example) json:

```
{
"1": {
    "2": {
        "3": {
            "9": 10,
            "8": 11,
            "7": 12
        },
        "4": {
            "9": 13,
            "8": 14,
            "7": 15
        },
        "5": {
            "9": 16,
            "8": 17,
            "7": 18
        },
        "6": {
            "9": 19,
            "8": 20,
            "7": 21
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From here I will start off with "2", so I do `json.loads(array)['1']`

Now I want to get each of the names ("3", "4", "5", "6") like so:

```
3
4
5
6
```

And then the value of "9":

```
3 (10)
4 (13)
5 (16)
6 (19)
```

The value of "9" should be a separate string, so to get the above, I'd do something like `"%s (%s)" % (string, string2)`

Now I'm not even sure if starting with "2" is necessary, but I wanted to show what I've tried so far.

Comment: As @wim said, as a courtesy, please provide valid JSON. You need to remove the comma after `"7": ...` in each of the inner-most values, and add a final closing `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this solution is to break the large JSON block into smaller chunks.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


text = '''{
"1": {
    "2": {
        "3": {"9": 10, "8": 11, "7": 12},
        "4": {"9": 13, "8": 14, "7": 15},
        "5": {"9": 16, "8": 17, "7": 18},
        "6": {"9": 19, "8": 20, "7": 21}
        }
    }
}
'''

block = json.loads(text)
block2 = block['1']['2']
for key, sub_block in block2.iteritems():
    print '%s (%s)' % (key, sub_block['9'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd point you towards `dict.items`:

```
y = json.loads(array)['1']['2']
list(map(lambda i: (i[0],i[1]['9']), y.items()))
```

This will return a list of key-value pairs, which you might print with something similar to what you posed in your question:

```
[('6', 19),('5',16),('3',10),('4',13)]
```

What `items` does is return a list of the raw key-value pairs in the dictionary object (what `json.loads` returns), which I then passed through a `map` call to look up the `'9'` key of the value portion.